# deleting elements of a vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have a vector for storing the pointers of all objects (created by `new`) of a class.
I have an int member variable (called *id*) for each object which stores the index of the vector element in which the address of that object is stored.
This method helps me to call any object with the help of *id*.
The *id* is assigned in the constructor with the help of a static variable, which is incremented each time an object is created.
My problem is that when i delete an object, i cannot delete the vector element (free the memory taken by that element, as my vector is created dynamically) (because if i delete it, then the indexes of all the next elements will decrease by 1).
So I would like to know a method by which i can free the memory from the vector but not cause change in indexes of other elements.
Please tell me a method which doesn't consume a lot of time. (methods like rearranging elements & then changing *id* of each object will consume a lot of time!)
I may have around 1000 such objects which may consume a lot of time if i delete the 1st element & do rearrangement as mentioned above.
THANK YOU

Comment: 1) Use paragraphs, 2) post some code.

Comment: Reindexing a thousand objects won't take very long at all (!).  Reindexing 1000,000 might be something worth optimising.  Regardless, you could keep two vectors, one containing deleted indxes and the original vector.  Every time you delete an item, you set its contents to null and add the index to the set of deleted indices.  Whenever you add a new item, you first check to see if there's a free index in the list of deleted indices.  If there is, you reuse that index, otherwise you add one to the vector.

Comment: Yes. I) Use paragraphs. II) Post some code.

Comment: Konrad's idea is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using a `map<int,your_object_type*>` instead of a `vector<your_object_type*>`. Then you won't need to 'reindex' or (more importantly, I think) reassign IDs when an item is deleted.

Comment: since i require itteration frequently & vectors are best at it, i have decided to use vectots

Comment: @CAD_coding A map isn't bad at iterating, either.  I don't think that it's significantly slower than a vector.  It does give bad locality, but since your vector only contains pointers, and not the objects themselves, you've got that anyway.  The main difference is in lookup: looking up an object from its key in a vector is almost instantaneous, O(1) with a very, very small constant; looking up the object in a map is O(lg n), with a much larger constant factor as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze so suppose i have 1000 elements in a map, then how much time would i require to search for an element using operator[int]....int is the key

Comment: Access to a `map` is O(ln n); in my experience, this is usually not the issue for data sets with only 1000 elements.  The constant factor is large, however.  If you can control the integral values, you're probably better off using `vector`, and finding some means of reusing the indexes of deleted elements.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to rearrange *one* element: `swap` the last element of the vector to the position of the element to delete, then delete the last element.

```
int to_delete = …;
swap(my_vec[to_delete], my_vec[my_vec.end() - 1]);
my_vec[to_delete].index = to_delete;
delete my_vec.back();
```

Comment: Great idea.  Not my first thought.

Comment: @Konrad but what if i have stored the id of the last element somewhere which may come in the flow after the swaping.
this will cause an error i guess because then that id wouldnt exist or may refer to some other element

Comment: +1 If you need to be sure the id of an object never changes, have a look at my answer.

Comment: @CAD_coding Ah, you didn’t mention this. Well, obviously if you cannot find all occurrences of the index, then you cannot rearrange the items. *Why* do you store these indices, though? Why not rather maintain pointers to your objects?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, if i dont do this then i will have to pass on the address everytime i reach the end of a function, otherwise i would loose the address of that object when that function goes out of scope

Comment: example:
func1{
apple *a_object = new apple;
//if i dont return this address, i will loose this address
}
func2
{
func1();
//i dont have address of a_object
}

Comment: @KonradRudolph i guess there is no solution to my problem then! :(

Comment: @CAD_coding: but you already have to pass the ID anyway! Passing the ID or the address is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Your design is quite unusual. If you want the location of objects to stay put, using a vector isn't your best option. You can store the objects in a list, set or map, which all preserve the location of objects when one is removed. That way you can access objects via pointer instead of id (although with map you can use both)

If you absolutely have to use a vector for some reason, you can use the "swap and pop" trick to delete objects. When an object is deleted, swap it with the last element in the vector, and then call pop_back() to remove the last element. You would then need to update the element you just moved with it's new ID. But the operation runs in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a second list of reusable slots/ids which you check first every time you new an element. When you delete an element you add the id of the element to the list of reusable ids:

```
//Somewhere in the code
vector<Object*> s_objects;
vector<int> s_freeIds;

//On new:
if (s_freeIds.empty())
{
   s_objects.push_back(new Object());
   s_objects.back().id = s_objects.size() - 1;
}
else
{
    int id = s_freeIds.back();
    s_freeIds.pop_back();
    s_objects[id] = new Object();
    s_objects[id].id = id;
}

//On delete
s_freeIds.push_back(this->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be to not delete the element from the vector
at all, but simply replace it with a null pointer.  This does mean that
when iterating over the complete vector, you have to check for null
pointers, but that isn't usually a big problem.  And to prevent the
vector from growing infinitely, you have to be able to reuse the slots;
either you scan the vector for a null pointer (`std::find`) on
insertion, or you maintain some sort of list of free slots.

Note that if your id is to be used as an index into the vector, you
don't want to generate it independently.  If you insert using
`push_back` (because there were no null pointers in the vector), the id
is `v.size() - 1` after the `push_back`, or simply `v.size()` before; if
you insert at a specific place, using the iterator returned by 
`std::find`, then the identifier is that iterator - `v.begin()`.  If
you're just using linear search (and with a vector as small as 1000
elements, this is likely sufficient), then something like the following
should work:

```
//      returns index of inserted element
int
insertIntoVector( std::vector<MyType*>& index, MyType* newObject )
{
    std::vector<MyType*>::iterator position
            = std::find( index.begin(), index.end(), NULL );
    int results = position - index.begin();
    if ( position == index.end() ) {
        index.push_back( newObject );
    } else {
        *position = newObject;
    }
    return results;
}
```

If you're caching the free slots, replace the `std::find` with the
corresponding code to find the free slot.

Answer (score 0):

The real question: why are you using a `vector` ?

First, about generating IDs:

```
typedef size_t ID;

static ID& accessID() { static ID id = 0; return id; }

ID currentID() { return accessID(); }
ID newID() { return ++accessID(); }
```

Second, this is a typical factory situation, so let us provide a `Factory` implementation.

```
class ObjectFactory {
  typedef std::unordered_map<ID, Object> Register;

public:
  Object& create() {
    ID const id = newID();
    return register.insert(std::make_pair(id, Object(id))).first->second;
  }

  Object* access(ID id) {
    Register::iterator it = register.find(id);
    return it == register.end() ? nullptr : &it->second;
  }

  Object const* get(ID id) const {
    Register::const_iterator it = register.find(id);
    return it == register.end() ? nullptr : &it->second;
  }

  bool remove(ID id) {
    return register.erase(id);
  }

private:
  Register register;
};
```

You may choose to make the current ID a member of the factory, or keep it apart in case you want different factories and are afraid of mixing up the IDs.

Comment: considering the answer from michael, i have now decided to use map.
anyways thank you